# react-admin: When to first get data pass by a List to a DataGrid

Tags: react-admin

I have a custom component that substitute the DataGrid component, and it uses state, so i want to initiate the state prop with an array of boolean items representing the records. 
My problem is where to initiate the state prop of my component since i need to have access to the records coming from the back-end first.

According to the docs, the List component "...passes the data to an iterator view - usually Datagrid..." and looking at the source code it does so in the componentDidMount and the componentWillRecibeProps methods.
But i'm unable to work it out so far.

In a nutshell, 
When is the data of DataGrid gets loaded into it?

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify data coming from back-end before rendering these ways

1. Probably the most suitable place to modify it is in `convertHTTPResponse` in `dataProvider.js`

**dataProvider.js:**

```
const convertHTTPResponse = async (response, type, resource, params) => {
  let json;
  switch (type) {
    case GET_LIST:
    case GET_MANY:
    case GET_MANY_REFERENCE:
      json = await response.json();
      const total = response.headers.get('x-total-count');
      return {
        data: json.map(d => /* modify data here */),
        total: parseInt(total, 10)
      };
<..>

export default (type, resource, params) => {
<..>
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then(res => convertHTTPResponse(res, type, resource, params));
};
```

2. Modify data in your custom component

```js
const ListComponent = (({ classes, ...props }) => (
  <List {...props}>
    <YourCustomComponent />
  </List>
));

const YourCustomComponent = ({ ids, data, basePath }) => {
  // modify data here
  return // 
};
```